# Convert from "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" to "yyyy-MM-dd" AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

The problem I am having with is that since I am using `ng-model`, I cannot do something like `{{ myDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd" }}`.

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
   <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" ng-model="currentAccount.InceptionDate" ng-init="currentAccount.InceptionDate = parseDate(currentAccount.InceptionDate)">
</div>
```

I made a function to initialize the date in my controller

```
$scope.parseDate = function (date) {
   return new Date(Date.parse(date));
}
```

I put a break point at the `return` statement. It says that `date` is undefined. 
Another thing is that, `InceptionDate` when defined in my `Account.cs` class, its type is `DateTime`, not `string`. I'm not sure if this is the actual cause.

If my HTML looks like this, it works fine, but the date is not in the format I want (it is showing `2015-08-10T00:00:00`):

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentAccount.InceptionDate" >
</div>
```

Comment: have you used moment.js . you can use $window to get moment object and parse it any way www.momentjs.com/

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? Not a lot of context right now with what you've written.

Answer (score 3):

If `currentAccount.InceptionDate` is a both a `Date` object and a scope variable, you should be able to just do:

```
{{currentAccount.InceptionDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rpgillespie/d65e5yfy/1/

Comment: currentAccount is, but InceptionDate is not. currentAccount is an object of the Account.cs class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you update the fiddle to fit your scenario?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d65e5yfy/3/ Oh sorry I thought it would update your fiddle as well.

Comment: First of all, you don't have a closing bracket on `service`. Second of all, I don't have access to your `accountResource.detail.query` API. 

You'll need to fill in dummy data for `currentAccount`. Make it simulate the real thing.

Comment: Third of all, `$scope.currentAccount = accountFactory.currentAccount;` will always return an empty object.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d65e5yfy/5/ Updated. Well I have a function that actually assigns the value. I mean everything works fine if I just set <input type="text">. I use ng-model because the user would want to change the value in the UI.

Comment: Getting an input of type "datetime-local" playing nice with angular is [possible](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D), but kind of fickle as the feature isn't well implemented and supported in most browsers yet. You'd be better off using a third-party datepicker like the bootstrap one.